# Search cell in Excel sheet using part of text C#.net 4.0

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, vb6, excel-2007

Office.Interop.Excel to generate excel report.

I have predefined excel template that I am loading and replacing text by using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel objects. My problem is, when I use part of text to search cell in excel sheet it doesn't work but in my Old VB 6 code it works fine my code is like this which is working in VB6 and not working in c#.4

**Excel sheet Cell which I need to find**

Row "2" , Column "D" having text "«Name»"

**VB 6 Code (Working)**

```
Dim m_objExcelSheet As Object
Dim objRange As Object

'Note : here has extra code  to load Excel template file
'When I use only part of text to find cell its working fine
objRange = m_objExcelSheet.cells.Find(what:=Chr(171))
```

**c#.net 4.0 (Not Working)**

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet objExcelSheet;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range objRange ;

//Note : here has extra code  to load Excel template file
//This doesn't work, it returns null
objRange = objExcelSheet.Cells.Find((char)(171), LookAt: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart);

//I tried this as well but this also doesn't work
objRange = objExcelSheet.Cells.Find((char)(171), Type.Missing,
                                            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                                            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false,
                                            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

//But if I give full text to find it works fine
objRange = objExcelSheet.Cells.Find((char)(171) + "Name" + (char)(187));
```

Is any one have any idea, how can I search cell by giving part of text

Answer (score 1):

Got it

I have to use "*" with search string like this

```
objRange = objExcelSheet.Cells.Find((char)(171) + "*");
```